# table name concatenation for dynamic query execution in oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have 30 tables namely second_data_0, second_data_1,..........,second_data_29. I'm joining these tables with another table first_data one-by-one and storing result in a temporary table in a Mysql stored procedure(given below). Could someone tell me how to do this in an oracle procedure especially the `SET @s = CONCAT("INSERT INTO firstTemp SELECT a.ID,b.CLSNO,b.FEES,b.FEES_T,b.FEES_DT FROM first_data a, second_data_",i," b WHERE a.CLASS_NO = b.CLSNO AND (b.FEES < a.FEES_AMOUNT) AND b.FEES_DT BETWEEN DATE('2017-11-20') AND DATE('2017-12-25')");` part?

```
    SET i = 1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE firstTemp
SELECT a.ID,b.CLSNO,b.FEES,b.FEES_T,b.FEES_DT FROM first_data a, second_data_0 b WHERE a.CLASS_NO = b.CLSNO AND (b.FEES < a.FEES_AMOUNT) AND b.FEES_DT BETWEEN DATE('2017-11-20') AND DATE('2017-12-25');
label1: WHILE i < 30 DO
    SET @s = CONCAT("INSERT INTO firstTemp SELECT a.ID,b.CLSNO,b.FEES,b.FEES_T,b.FEES_DT FROM first_data a, second_data_",i," b WHERE a.CLASS_NO = b.CLSNO AND (b.FEES < a.FEES_AMOUNT) AND b.FEES_DT BETWEEN DATE('2017-11-20') AND DATE('2017-12-25')");
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE label1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important tip before you start: don't use the comma (a,b) syntax for `JOINS`, use the `JOIN ON` syntax.

You can use a numeric `FOR LOOP` in PL/SQL for your purpose.

```
BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
          '
    CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE firstTemp

    AS
       SELECT a.ID,
              b.CLSNO,
              b.FEES,
              b.FEES_T,
              b.FEES_DT
         FROM first_data a
              JOIN second_data_0 b
                 ON a.CLASS_NO = b.CLSNO AND b.FEES < a.FEES_AMOUNT
        WHERE b.FEES_DT BETWEEN DATE ''2017-11-20'' AND DATE ''2017-12-25''';

       FOR i IN 1 .. 30
       LOOP
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
                '
    INSERT INTO firstTemp
       SELECT a.ID,
              b.CLSNO,
              b.FEES,
              b.FEES_T,
              b.FEES_DT
         FROM first_data a JOIN second_data_'
         || i
         || ' b ON a.CLASS_NO = b.CLSNO AND b.FEES < a.FEES_AMOUNT WHERE b.FEES_DT
BETWEEN DATE ''2017-11-20'' AND DATE ''2017-12-25''';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
stmt := 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE firstTemp(list if columns) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS';
execute immediate stmt;

WHILE (i < 30) loop
stmt2 := 'INSERT INTO firstTemp values( SELECT a.ID,b.CLSNO,b.FEES,b.FEES_T,b.FEES_DT FROM first_data a, second_data_' || i ||
         ' b WHERE a.CLASS_NO = b.CLSNO AND (b.FEES < a.FEES_AMOUNT) AND b.FEES_DT BETWEEN DATE(''2017-11-20'') AND DATE(''2017-12-25''))';
execute immediate stmt2;
i := i + 1;
end loop;
```

both stmt and stmt2 are long variable and i is an integer.